# The path in the launch.json keep automatically changing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When I start debugging or re-opening the VSCode window. Some path in launch.json just keep changing (especially `cwd` and `program`). It is very annoying because I have to change the path back to the path I want. Without fixing it, I can not start debugging because VSCode complains that my path is incorrect.

**Here my desired path**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [

    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
    }
  ]
}
```

**But the path changed to**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "d:/CODE/Learn_Space/Cpp",
      "program": "d:/CODE/Learn_Space/Cpp/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have been trying to delete and create the launch.json file again and again. But the same issue kept appreared. I don't know how to fix it. Anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you eliminated the possibility that a plugin is causing this? If the answer is yes, you may consider mentioning it in the question.

Comment: The `C/C++ Runner` plugin would be my guess, presumably it automatically creates launch.json for you

Comment: potentially related: https://github.com/franneck94/Vscode-C-Cpp-Runner/issues/140

Comment: never mind. above issue ticket probably not related. I'd suggest to [raise an issue ticket](https://github.com/franneck94/Vscode-C-Cpp-Runner/issues/new) of your own. If you do, please comment here with a link to your issue ticket.

Comment: thanks guys, it was the plugin. After I deleted it, everything seemed to be normal again

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved. After I deleted the C/C++ Runner extension in VS Code, the problem was gone.